# Code signing Error: Application failed codesign verification

Tags: ios, xcode, osx-lion

I am very new to iOS development, I have an app all set and ready to be distributed, but I seem to get this error every single time I run the application on my DEVICE only, the iOS simulator works just fine. Heres the full error:

> Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, contains disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate. (-19011)

Here's the entire log:

```
Validate "/Users/masonsocha/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Multibrowser-brgeiknbjgrywwehhohafjwxjqnk/Build/Products/App Store-iphoneos/Multibrowser.app"
    cd /Users/masonsocha/Desktop/Apps/MultiBrowser
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    setenv PRODUCT_TYPE com.apple.product-type.application
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/Validation "/Users/masonsocha/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Multibrowser-brgeiknbjgrywwehhohafjwxjqnk/Build/Products/App Store-iphoneos/Multibrowser.app"

warning: Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, contains disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate. (-19011)
Executable=/Users/masonsocha/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Multibrowser-brgeiknbjgrywwehhohafjwxjqnk/Build/Products/App Store-iphoneos/Multibrowser.app/Multibrowser
codesign_wrapper-0.7.10: using Apple CA for profile evaluation
AssertMacros: trust_result == kSecTrustResultUnspecified,  file: codesign_wrapper.c, line: 594
AssertMacros: profile,  file: codesign_wrapper.c, line: 918
codesign_wrapper-0.7.10: Failed to load provision profile from: /Users/masonsocha/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Multibrowser-brgeiknbjgrywwehhohafjwxjqnk/Build/Products/App Store-iphoneos/Multibrowser.app/embedded.mobileprovision
 - (null)
```

I have already tried shortening the length of the project name, that did not help, I am currently using OSX Lion, on Xcode 4.3.2. I have spent all night pulling my hair out, please help!

Comment: Are you trying to build for a device to test, or to build to distribute to the App Store?

Comment: Sounds like you maybe haven't even setup code signing according to this.

> The signature was invalid, contains disallowed entitlements, or it was
> not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate.

Did you follow any of the instructions on the developer portal to get your certificates?  Or are you simply changing from the simulator to device and hoping it will run?

Comment: For those of you looking for up to date solution - April 2013 based, please follow:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2250/_index.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the exact same issue..

Go to Keychain Access

1. Verify that you have your Public and Private keys set up correctly. This is a good reference https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn2250/_index.html
2. I had previously adjusted my Keychain Certificate Preferences to make Outlook work but that pretty much screwed up XCode code signing..

After I set these to the "best attempt" setting (see screenshot) validation worked fine

[image]

Answer (score 19):

May be xcode selects one of the development profile to sign the code with it.

Make sure it uses the distribution profile

press the project, in the Build Settings -> Code Signing section expand Code Signing Identity -> Release - > make sure that Any iOS SDK is referring to distribution profile.

Comment: Thanks!  I ran into this because my release code signing entity was set to match the dev one for Test Flight.

Answer (score 3):

You could solve it is not leaving the profile selection to xcode. Manually select the correct **release** profile in the project settings and it will go through.

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue even after checking all signing stuff.  I had the old "Can be debugged" setting in my entitlements file.  Switching it to get-task-allowed fixed the problem. Apple has [instructions on how to debug signing issues](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-TNTAG8).

Comment: Thanks for all the replies everyone, but i solved the problem, i had selected my specific distribution provisioning profile, i tried selecting the recommended setting were it automatically selects a valid profile, and it worked just fine:D

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem but found that none of the above issues solved it. Eventually I found the solution by working through Apple's Technical Note (https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn2250/_index.html) on the subject.

The specific problem in my case was an asset that was either missing or was hidden (I didn't find out which), but that wasn't flagged as a problem file anywhere else in the build process. I've outlined the steps I took to discover this below.

1. Archive the build, save for adhoc deployment.
2. Navigate to the ipa in finder, rename to .zip.
3. Double-click to unarchive, open the 'Payload' folder
4. Open a Terminal, and enter the following:

   codesign --verify -vvvv -R='anchor apple generic and certificate 1[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.2.1] exists and (certificate leaf[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.2] exists or certificate leaf[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.4] exists)' /Path/to/your/app.app
5. Instead of entering /Path/to/your/app.app, drag and drop the *.app file from the Payload folder into the terminal, ensure there's a space between the end of the command and the filename, and hit return.

I got an error in the output saying 'a sealed resource is missing or invalid', with the name of the file causing the problem (it began with  a dot, which may have been the problem). When I searched for the filename in the XCode project browser I found the file, but when I looked in the Finder, it wasn't on disk.

The fix was simply to remove the file from the XCode project browser, and the error went away.  I would definitely say to anyone getting a similar problem - work through Apple's tech notes. They're a bit badly worded but the solution is likely to be in there somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by:

- Changing the Automatic Profile Selector value from "iPhone Developer" to "iPhone Distribution" according to section [Assigning Provisioning Profiles to Build Configurations](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-TNTAG13).
- Download the Distribution Provisioning Profile and double-click on it in order to add it.