# iPhone Application Loader Troubleshooting

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, application-loader

I'm trying to upload the next version of my iPhone application through application loader, but I receive this error...

```
Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, contains disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate.
```

I'm not exactly sure if this is what is wrong, but I took a screenshot of Xcode to show you guys...

[image]

I've submitted my application via Application loader before, and I think I had the same problem, but I can't remember what I did...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Code signing Error: Application failed codesign verification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9985320/code-signing-error-application-failed-codesign-verification)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with Xcode 4, you can use it to submit apps to the App Store. See [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/DistApps/DistApps.html)
link for more information on how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Organizer in Xcode and have a loot at your provisioning profiles. How's their status? Are they marked with "!"?

Comment: Did you use an "Entitlements.plist" for Ad-Hoc distribution in the meantime? 
Is your developer-certificate still valid? (Check into iOS Dev Center -> Provisioning Center and re-build/re-download your profiles)

Comment: No I didn't use Entitlements.plist, but I just re-downloaded my provisioning profile, but still no luck...