# Application Failed Codesign Warning when Archiving

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Code signing Error: Application failed codesign verification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9985320/code-signing-error-application-failed-codesign-verification)

So I know there have been questions just like this one several times, but none of them seem to answer exactly what I am looking for. I found the apple documentation on how to fix this problem and I have systematically gone through and checked every single thing that is wrong, and nearly lost my mind in the process. The only possible option that I have left to try is to completely start a new project and go through the entire provisioning process again, which I would really rather not do. Please, if you have a solution, I would really appreciate any advice you may have.

For **this error**

```
warning: Application failed codesign verification. The signature was invalid, 
    contains disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with an iPhone 
    Distribution Certificate. (-19011)
Executable=/Users/aaronkawalsky/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PetPocket-
    ctqkmlfzeawgfdcqlbsslqfrodvt/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/
    PetPocket/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/PetPocket.app/
    PETPocket
codesign_wrapper-4.1: using Apple CA for profile evaluation
/Users/aaronkawalsky/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PetPocket-  
    ctqkmlfzeawgfdcqlbsslqfrodvt/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/
    PetPocket/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/PetPocket.app:
a sealed resource is missing or invalid In architecture: armv7
codesign_wrapper-4.1: failed to execute codesign(1)
 - (null)
```

This is the end of my **build log**

```
CodeSign
/Users/aaronkawalsky/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PetPocket-
        ctqkmlfzeawgfdcqlbsslqfrodvt/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/
        PetPocket/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/PetPocket.app
    cd /Users/aaronkawalsky/Documents/petpocketiphone/trunk/PetPocket
    setenv CODESIGN_ALLOCATE /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/
        Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/
        iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/
        Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign 57c0004c5de1c69a8edfdfd0fa604a772a250365
--resource-rules=/Users/aaronkawalsky/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
        PetPocket-ctqkmlfzeawgfdcqlbsslqfrodvt/Build/Intermediates/
        ArchiveIntermediates/PetPocket/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/
        UninstalledProducts/PetPocket.app/ResourceRules.plist
--entitlements /Users/aaronkawalsky/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
        PetPocket-ctqkmlfzeawgfdcqlbsslqfrodvt/Build/Intermediates/
        ArchiveIntermediates/PetPocket/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/
        PetPocket.build/Release-iphoneos/PetPocket.build/PetPocket.xcent
/Users/aaronkawalsky/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
        PetPocket-ctqkmlfzeawgfdcqlbsslqfrodvt/Build/Intermediates/
        ArchiveIntermediates/PetPocket/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/
        UninstalledProducts/PetPocket.app

Validate
/Users/aaronkawalsky/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
        PetPocket-ctqkmlfzeawgfdcqlbsslqfrodvt/Build/Intermediates/
        ArchiveIntermediates/PetPocket/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/
        UninstalledProducts/PetPocket.app
    cd /Users/aaronkawalsky/Documents/petpocketiphone/trunk/PetPocket
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/
        Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/
        Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    setenv PRODUCT_TYPE com.apple.product-type.application
        /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/
        Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/Validation
/Users/aaronkawalsky/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
        PetPocket-ctqkmlfzeawgfdcqlbsslqfrodvt/Build/Intermediates/
        ArchiveIntermediates/PetPocket/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/
        UninstalledProducts/PetPocket.app
```

Again, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9985320/code-signing-error-application-failed-codesign-verification

Comment: Believe me I have seen it and tried every solution they proposed, including for the link attached below in that question.

Comment: This problem is seen when you try to build it on the device right? i just need to know that whether you can run it on the simulator or not?

Comment: Yeah i can run on it on the simulator fine, I can even deploy it to my own device. I am just getting this warning when archiving the application. Weirdly, though, although I got the warning I was still able to distribute the program. I would still rather get rid of the warning though.