# Application failed codesign verification - Command line used by Application Loader?

Tags: iphone, validation, codesign, application-loader

This appears in the Application loader but I cannot investigate as everything looks correct.

Can someone tell me how to get the Validation tool output to show the full verbose log of why I'm getting this.

I'm currently running:

```
PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin"

PRODUCT_TYPE=com.apple.product-type.application

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/Validation ~/Desktop/EstateTest/Deliver/appAppStore.ipa
```

No output & exit code == 0

So in summary. What command is Application Loader running here that I am not in the terminal.
Also. Running codesign --verify checks also returns okay.

Thanks

Comment: Check this url

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9985320/code-signing-error-application-failed-codesign-verification

Comment: @VineeshTP I've checked & my settings for Keychain preferences look fine. Cheers though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out why it was failing code sign validation. I had generated the the Push Certificates before generating the certificates/provisions.

Looking inside my AppStore.provision showed no entitlements section in the plist xml & thats how I knew.