# iOS Distribution Fails Codesign

Tags: xcode, app-store, distribution, code-signing, xcode4.6

I'm trying to deploy my app to the store but running into dreaded code sign problems. I've refreshed all my provisioning profiles etc on my local machine (I hope I don't have to remake them in the provisioning portal) but still no luck. My app does use background location checks as defined in the plist but besides that I don't know what disallowed entitlements it could be referring to. The only other possible issue could be that I renamed my app partway through development but I've updated all my profiles, target info, etc. to match the new name. I'm at a loss. I can build and run it fine, it just won't sign. See my complete warning log below:

```
Validate /Users/benchirlin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Yodlr-blhadxxlldqhvobcgzqdncvvaoao/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Yodlr/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Yodlr.app
    cd "/Users/benchirlin/Documents/Workspaces/Xcode Workspace/iFM"
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    setenv PRODUCT_TYPE com.apple.product-type.application
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/Validation /Users/benchirlin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Yodlr-blhadxxlldqhvobcgzqdncvvaoao/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Yodlr/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Yodlr.app

warning: Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, contains disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate. (-19011)Executable=/Users/benchirlin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Yodlr-blhadxxlldqhvobcgzqdncvvaoao/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Yodlr/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Yodlr.app/Yodlrcodesign_wrapper-4.1: using Apple CA for profile evaluation/Users/benchirlin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Yodlr-blhadxxlldqhvobcgzqdncvvaoao/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Yodlr/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Yodlr.app: valid on disk/Users/benchirlin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Yodlr-blhadxxlldqhvobcgzqdncvvaoao/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Yodlr/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Yodlr.app: satisfies its Designated Requirementtest-requirement: code failed to satisfy specified code requirement(s)codesign_wrapper-4.1: failed to execute codesign(1) - (null
```

Comment: make sure app status is : Ready to upload binary

Comment: Yep it is. Thanks. I get the error when making the archive, even before validating via iTunes Connect (though it pops up there as well)

Comment: check out accepted answer in this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9985320/code-signing-error-application-failed-codesign-verification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched my code signing identities to my wildcard distribution identity and it worked...finally!