# Code signing Error: Application failed codesign verification Xcode Archive

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode4

I have an iPhone application that has no errors and my app was Archiving normally then I ran into a problem validating my app im receiving the message “No identities are available for signing”.

So one question on Stack told me to download my Distribution Certificate and drag it into my app. I did that then I got the following error.

I deleted the file out my project it runs fine but when I archive my app I get a warning. I have tried a number of things to no avail.

```
(null):  Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, contains disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate. (-19011) 


Validate /Users/blakeloizides/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Novolam-gwqochjjqgryxnedazbaosfjksmz/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Novolam/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Novolam.app
    cd /Users/blakeloizides/NETNRG/Novolam
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    setenv PRODUCT_TYPE com.apple.product-type.application
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/Validation /Users/blakeloizides/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Novolam-gwqochjjqgryxnedazbaosfjksmz/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Novolam/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Novolam.app

warning: Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, contains disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate. (-19011)Executable=/Users/blakeloizides/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Novolam-gwqochjjqgryxnedazbaosfjksmz/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Novolam/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Novolam.app/Novolamcodesign_wrapper-4.1: using Apple CA for profile evaluation/Users/blakeloizides/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Novolam-gwqochjjqgryxnedazbaosfjksmz/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Novolam/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Novolam.app: valid on disk/Users/blakeloizides/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Novolam-gwqochjjqgryxnedazbaosfjksmz/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Novolam/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Novolam.app: satisfies its Designated Requirementtest-requirement: code failed to satisfy specified code requirement(s)codesign_wrapper-4.1: failed to execute codesign(1) - (null
```

Comment: if you go in Organizer and see the Provisioning profiles status? does it show you valid status with green tick?

Comment: yes it shows me a tick under teams ...

Comment: then you should make sure you are using the right profiles for signing the product, and you will have to sign the target of the project also

Comment: What do the options under Code Signing in target and project settings say?

Answer (score 0):

Delete your `Provisioning Profile` in your `iPhone Configuration Utility` and Download the new one and add to your library. You have to go to `Keychain Access -> Preferences` and select **Best Attempt** or **Off** your following two things:

```
 1. Online Certificate Status Protocol (OCSP)
 2. Certificate Revocation List (CRL)
```

Check this answer for [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9985320/code-signing-error-application-failed-codesign-verification#answer-10059876)