# Issue during validation

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

I have 2 issues during validation.

1. iPhone/iPod Touch: Info.plist: Unable to verify icon dimensions, no icon found. You must define CFBundleIcons, CFBundleIconFiles, CFBundleIconFile, or provide a default Icon.png that is 57x57.
2. Application failed codesign verification. The signature was invalid, constains disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with an iPhone distribution Certificate.

For the first issue I have included my icon with name icon_57x57.png and icon_114x114.png. I also have sign it in my info.plist but still found this issue. For the second issue I have change my provisioning to a distribution one.

Comment: your icon should be `Icon.png` (57x57) `Icon@2x.png` (114x114). please correct the names of your icon files

Comment: I have already changed it, but I still got this issue during validation..

Comment: Try cleaning your project. or removing Icon files and adding them again.

Comment: I have restart my xcode and do like you have said, but I still got the same issues.

Answer (score 0):

**For first solution**

for info.plist

[image]

Change it to this.

[image]

and also you can set here on setting APP Icons. It gives perfect size if you set wrong image.

[image]

**For Second**

[Code signing Error: Application failed codesign verification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9985320/code-signing-error-application-failed-codesign-verification)

Comment: I have tried your first solution, and I don't have the last line like yours. But I have signed all off the icons in info.plist and still the same.